# Filter Data by Day of Week and Time of Day

Tags: influxdb

I am new to flux and InfluxDB. I’ve been working my way through sorting some data out that I am bringing in from my SCADA system and getting it into units that correspond with how we are billed from our power supplier.

I have one task configured that condenses my two-minutely data down into 30-minute average values throughout the day. This task runs at minute 0 and minute 30 of every hour, day, month, and day of week, takes data from the bucket that I push the raw data into, averages the previous 30 minutes worth of data together, and pushes it into a new bucket called SCADA_Integrated, generally within a few seconds of minutes 0 and 30 each hour.

Now, I want to write another task that will look through the data in SCADA_Integrated and filter it so that only the data inside the billing period used by our power provider is included. This includes the 30-minute intervals on Monday through Saturday, beginning at noon and ending at 10:00 PM. However, I can’t just use the regular hourSelection() function to do this, because my interval average data is written a few seconds after the half-hour that represents the end of the interval. Examples of this are that there will be an interval with a timestamp of 12:00:02 that should not be in the data that I pick up, because it was actually the average of the values from 11:30 - 12:00. And, I need to pick up the interval with a timestamp of, say, 22:00:03 because it includes the data from 21:30 - 22:00.

To try to evaluate this, I wrote the following query:

```
import "date"

option task = {name: "System TPP-MCL Filter", cron: "0,30 * * * *"}

from(bucket: "SCADA_Integrated")
    |> range(start: -30m)
    |> filter(
        fn: (r) =>
            r._measurement == "System RTU" and r._field == "kW_CV" and r.point_id == "Total System kVA"
    )
    |> filter(fn: (r) => 
            date.weekDay(t: r._time) >= 1 and 
            date.weekDay(t: r._time) <= 6 and
            ( date.hour(t: r._time) > 12 or ( date.hour(t: r._time) = 12 and date.minute(t: r._time) >= 1 )) and
            ( date.hour(t: r._time) < 22 or ( date.hour(t: r._time) = 22 and date.minute(t: r._time) <= 1 ))
    )
   |> to(bucket: "SCADA_TPP-MCL")
```

However, when I try to save this, I get an error:

> failed to update task: loc 0:0-0:0: unknown operator “<INVALID_OP>”

If I remove these two rows:

```
    ( date.hour(t: r._time) > 12 or ( date.hour(t: r._time) = 12 and date.minute(t: r._time) >= 1 )) and
    ( date.hour(t: r._time) < 22 or ( date.hour(t: r._time) = 22 and date.minute(t: r._time) <= 1 ))
```

the task will save. I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong here. I figure that it must be pretty basic, but I just can’t find it.  I have searched around and really haven't found another way to get the time period that I need with the little bit of "fudge factor" that I need at the beginning of the hours.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

And, I finally found the problem, and it was a stupid mistake.  The "Equal To" comparator is == not = and that is why it did not understand my operator in there.  I fixed that, and the query works beautifully.

Comment: That is one of the most annoying things when you come from a VB-esque language that  allows this = that to be just that and doesnt need to be like no , this is equal equal to that .. the extra equal lets you know its really equal .. okay ... if you say so javascript formatting ..